# Installing and using virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to learn how to program using Django, but I am stuck dealing with some problems related to the use of `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`.

I am using a Mac with the following OSX `OS X El Capitan 10.11.3` with `Python 2.7.10` as default.

I have just recently downloaded `Python 3.5` and also `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` using the following commands in the terminal:

```
pip install virtualenv
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

This seemed to work smoothly, and so I followed the installation guide found at [Virtualenvwrapper Installation Guide](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) in order to correctly modify the `.bash_profile` so that the `virtualenvwrapper` is loaded correctly.

However, there are some of the guidelines I do not fully understand and thus I am not able to successfully set up the `virtualenvwrapper`.

The following lines are said to be added to the shell startup file:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

But when I installed the `virtualenvwrapper`, the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` was stored in the following path: `Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/`

In other words, there is no file called `virtualenvwrapper.sh` at `/usr/local/bin/`.

My shell startup file currently looks like this:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

When I now try to write the following code in terminal:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

the following outputs:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried to change the path of the source in the `.bash_profile` to the following:

```
source Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

which is where the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` file is located. This however, gives the following output:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Any suggestions as to how I should fix this? I am sorry for the length of the question, but I wanted to explain the problem thoroughly.

I would be really thankful for any answers :)

Answer (score 0):

`virtualenvwrapper.sh` should be in your path somewhere. The simplest solution is tp change the `source` statement to read

```
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
```

Note the back-ticks around the `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` part of the command.

That will find it in the path, wherever it actually lives. And yes, on a mac, it is often in `Library/Frameworks/` etc. But that should be on your path because part of the install for python will put it there.